Remove punctuation in a string
I wrote this function to remove punctuation. I tested everything and the problem seems to be the firstIndex variable failed to increase by 1 each loop.
I tried to increase the firstIndex by using Increment Operator but this variable only increase once only and reach max value at 1. I truly dont know to fix this
const textInput = "Hello world!"

const insensitiveText = textInput.toLocaleLowerCase();

const letters = insensitiveText.split("");

const removePunctuation = (letters) =>{
    const tempArray = new Array();
    for( const i in letters){
        var firstIndex = 0;
        if(letters[i].charCodeAt() > 96 && letters[i].charCodeAt() < 123){ // This loop succeeded in removePunctuation;
            tempArray[firstIndex] = letters[i];
            firstIndex = firstIndex + 1;
        }
    }
    return(tempArray);
}


move var firstIndex = 0; outside the loop

There's no point in the variable in the first place. Just do tempArray.push(letters[i])

It would be really more efficient to use a Regular Expression to remove the characters.

Thanks a lot, im quite new to coding so any comment will be highly appreciated!

One of the first things to learn and one of the most important tools for a developer is the debugger. This is a great occasion to learn, how it works and how to find the problem yourself. Start the code in your debugger and step line by line through the code. Analyze the values and look for unexpected behavior. You should immediately see, why firstIndex only alternates between 0 and 1.

You should use a Regular expression
const text = 'Hello, how are you ?!'
const textWithoutPunctuation = text.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "") //Hello how are you

Regular Expression are really powerful I recommend you take a look at it
